# Download CSV from web service with Python 3

Tags: python, web-services, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to download a CSV file from a web service with Python 3.5.3. but I always get an error.

**Example**

I have this url

```
http://www.imdb.com/list/export?list_id=watchlist&author_id=ur72234145
```

If I open it with the browser it start downloading a *watchlist.csv* file.
I wrote the followng Phython code:

```
import urllib
url = 'http://www.imdb.com/list/export?list_id=watchlist&author_id=ur72234145'
response = urllib.request.Request(url)
html = response.read()
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(html)
```

but I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       html = response.read() AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'read'

what's wrong? If I use the same code with a static file path it works but it doesn't with the web service.

I don't think this is a duplicate question because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622753/download-file-from-web-service-in-python-3) is about PDF and how to manage PDF, not about CSV and how to download.

Comment: try url in browser `http://www.example.com/list/export?id=list_user&distance=long` and you see that there is no file.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use the url you use at the browser inside your code, say `url = "http://www.example.com/list/export?id=list_user&distance=long"`.

Comment: better show real url. Every page can be different and it may need different solution.

Comment: @furas I edited the question with a real world example.

Comment: @MarcosModenesi I used the same url. Maybe it was not clear so now I've edited the question...hope it's better for everybody.

Comment: I check this url in browser and it show me `ERROR 404` - so url is incorrect or maybe you have to be login to get it.

Comment: BTW: `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'output.csv')`

Comment: @furas is right. I have (now) understood that if you are not logged in the URL give you a 404 ERROR. That's a big problem!

Comment: you can login using `request` and `cookies` (and `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox) but it is easier with module [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `urlretrieve`

```
import urllib
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.imdb.com/list/export?list_id=watchlist&author_id=ur72234145'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'output.csv')
```

Because your url gives me `ERROR 404` it will be safer to use `try/except`

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

url = 'http://www.imdb.com/list/export?list_id=watchlist&author_id=ur72234145'

try:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'output.csv')
except urllib.error.HTTPError as ex:
    print('Problem:', ex)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a frequent user of `urllib` package, I tend to use `requests`, which is [HTTP for humans](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). But only by reading this [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#data) about `urllib` I can see that you are trying to `read` from an instance of `Request`, which gives you the error you are seeing. You should instead be reading from a `response`, which in turns you get **from** opening a request.

The following snippet is a simple modification of the official example in the link I provided, i.e., I didn't try it out, it's only here to show my point. I think it should give you something to work with.

```
url = 'http://www.imdb.com/list/export'
values = {'list_id' : 'watchlist',
          'author_id' : 'ur72234145'}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii') # data should be bytes
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)       # NOTE: you try to read from req
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   the_csv = response.read()                  # NOTE: you should read from the response,
                                              # which is the result of opening req
```